# Ember - Asynchronous data in nested view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ember.js

I have a list of messages. When a particular message is clicked it loads the details. This part works fine.

I want to load some other related data asynchronously when the clicked message is loaded. For that I'm nesting a view inside my `messageView`. However I am unable to load and access the data.

Here is my template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="message">

   {{#view "messageThread" contentBinding="this"}}

       {{#each message in view.getConversation}}

         <div>Message body</div>
         {{message.body}}

       {{/each}}


     </div>
   {{/view}}

</script>
```

Here is the `messageThreadView` used in the template above

```
App.MessageThreadView = Ember.View.extend({


     getConversation: function(){

       var msg = this.get('context').model;

       var sender_id = msg.sender.id;
       var recipient_id = msg.recipient.id;

       downloadConversation(recipient_id, sender_id);

       return this.get('current_conversation');

     }.property('current_conversation'),

});
```

Here is the asynchronous data load function called in the view above

```
function downloadConversation(recipient_id, sender_id){

   $.getJSON(<a url>)
     .then(function(data){

       App.set('current_conversation', data['objects']);
     });

 }
```

How do I get `view.getConversation` to work as expected i.e load the data when it becomes available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest pattern for asynchronous properties, especially when they are a collection.  You essentially return a collection reference (in this case convo), then you asynchronously populate that collection from the reference.

```
App.MessageThreadView = Ember.View.extend({
     getConversation: function(){

       var msg = this.get('context').model,
           sender_id = msg.sender.id,
           recipient_id = msg.recipient.id,
           convo = [];

       $.getJSON(<a url>).then(function(data){
         data.forEach(function(item){
           convo.pushObject(item);
         });
       });

       return convo;
     }.property(), // this should be watching sender and receipient

});
```

Comment: How do I make the view watch changes to the sender/recipient? I tried adding sender/recipient as properties to the view and doing a set inside the getConversation method. Doesn't seem to work. Any advice?

Comment: `property('context.sender.id', 'context.recipient.id')`... I'm assuming your passing in the controller to the view in the contextBinding, so you can skip the model step

Comment: Thanks again! I had to use `context.model.sender.id`. I don't have the properties explicitly setup on the controller. Probably that's why.